# no funciona el scroll al cargar el formulario de registrar en otra página

Tags: reactjs, hook

Me encuentro con un problema y es que el formulario al ingresar al link, no me funciona el scroll, para ello tengo que recargar la página.
Hay alguna manera de realizarlo.
Intente un effect para que recargara la página:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // window.location.href = window.location.href;
    // window.location.replace('');
}, []);
```

Cuando ingreso al link se queda cargando cada segundo.

por eso lo comenté.
No se como solucionarlo...
Adjunto codigo:
Create.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from '../../layout/Navbar';
import Footer from '../../layout/Footer';

const Create = () => {
    let history = useHistory(); //The useHistory hook gives you access to the history instance that you may use to navigate.
    // const { id } = useParams();  //The useParams() hook helps us to access the URL parameters from a current route.

    const [ fechaAct ] = useState(new Date());
    const [ date ] = useState(
        `${fechaAct.getFullYear()}-${fechaAct.getMonth() + 1 < 10
            ? '0' + (fechaAct.getMonth() + 1)
            : fechaAct.getMonth() + 1}-${fechaAct.getDate()}`
    );
    const [ hour ] = useState(`${fechaAct.getHours()}:${fechaAct.getMinutes() + 1}:${fechaAct.getSeconds()}`);

    const [ old, setold ] = useState('');
    const [ semana, setsemana ] = useState('');
    const [ tmonitoreo, settmonitoreo ] = useState('');
    const [ campana, setcampana ] = useState('');
    const [ id_agen, setid_agen ] = useState('');
    const [ nom_agen, setnom_agen ] = useState('');
    const [ coordi, setcoordi ] = useState('');
    const [ auditor, setauditor ] = useState('');
    const [ id_llamada, setid_llamada ] = useState('');
    const [ num_tel, setnum_tel ] = useState('');
    const [ f_llamada, setf_llamada ] = useState('');
    const [ tmo, settmo ] = useState('');
    const [ uno, setuno ] = useState(1);
    const [ quince, setquince ] = useState(1);
    const [ dieciseis, setdieciseis ] = useState(1);
    const [ enc, setenc ] = useState(100);
    const [ ec, setec ] = useState(100);
    const [ final, setfinal ] = useState(100);

    const calcularTotal = async (value, porcentaje, method, idDivModificar) => {
        document.getElementById(idDivModificar).style.backgroundColor = value == 1 ? '#e9ecef' : '#dc3545'; //colorea gris si cumple o rojo si no lo es
        document.getElementById(idDivModificar).style.color = value == 1 ? '#000' : '#fff'; //El texto es negro si cumple o si no blanco
        document.getElementById(idDivModificar).innerHTML = value == 1 ? porcentaje + '%' : '-' + porcentaje + '%';

        try {
            // var renc = await calEnc(value, porcentaje, method);
            // var rec = await calEc(value, method);
            // setfinal(await (rec == 0 ? 0 : renc));
        } catch (e) {
            alert('error ' + e);
        }
    };

    // const calEnc = (value, porcentaje, method) => {
    //  var r =
    //      method == false && value == 1 ? enc + porcentaje : method == false && value == 0 ? enc - porcentaje : enc;
    //  setenc(r);
    //  return r;
    // };

    // const calEc = (value, method) => {
    //  var r = method == true && value == 1 ? 100 : method == true && value == 0 ? 0 : ec;
    //  setec(r);
    //  return r;
    // };

    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar />
            <div className="container">
                <form id="formCreate">
                    <button
                        type="button"
                        className="btn btn-success"
                        style={{ width: '10em' }}
                        onClick={() => history.goBack()}
                    >
                        <i className="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left" />
                    </button>
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label>Antigüedad Agente</label>
                            <select
                                className="form-select form-control "
                                name="old"
                                id="old"
                                value={old}
                                onChange={(e) => setold(e.target.value)}
                                required
                            >
                                <option selected disabled value="">
                                    Seleccione
                                </option>
                                <option value="Nuevo">Nuevo</option>
                                <option value="Antiguo">Antiguo</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label>Semana</label>
                            <select
                                className="form-select form-control "
                                name="semana"
                                id="semana"
                                value={semana}
                                onChange={(e) => setsemana(e.target.value)}
                                required
                            >
                                <option selected disabled value="">
                                    Seleccione
                                </option>
                                <option value="Semana 1">Semana 1</option>
                                <option value="Semana 2">Semana 2</option>
                                <option value="Semana 3">Semana 3</option>
                                <option value="Semana 4">Semana 4</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label>Tipo de Monitoreo</label>
                            <select
                                className="form-select form-control "
                                name="tmonitoreo"
                                id="tmonitoreo"
                                value={tmonitoreo}
                                onChange={(e) => settmonitoreo(e.target.value)}
                                required
                            >
                                <option selected disabled value="">
                                    Seleccione
                                </option>
                                <option value="Grabado">Grabado</option>
                                <option value="Lado A Lado">Lado A Lado</option>
                                <option value="En Línea">En Línea</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label>Campaña</label>
                            <select
                                className="form-select form-control "
                                name="campana"
                                id="campana"
                                value={campana}
                                onChange={(e) => setcampana(e.target.value)}
                                required
                            >
                                <option selected disabled value="">
                                    Seleccione
                                </option>
                                <option value="IN HOGAR">IN HOGAR</option>
                                <option value="OUT HOGAR">OUT HOGAR</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label>Cédula de Ciudadanía</label>
                            <input
                                type="number"
                                className="form-control mb-4"
                                name="id_agen"
                                id="id_agen"
                                value={id_agen}
                                onChange={(e) => setid_agen(e.target.value)}
                                placeholder="Cédula de Cidadanía"
                                required
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label>Nombre Agente</label>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                className="form-control mb-4"
                                name="nom_agen"
                                id="nom_agen"
                                value={nom_agen}
                                onChange={(e) => setnom_agen(e.target.value)}
                                placeholder="Nombre Agente"
                                required
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label>Coordinador </label>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                className="form-control mb-4"
                                name="coordi"
                                id="coordi"
                                value={coordi}
                                onChange={(e) => setcoordi(e.target.value)}
                                placeholder="Coordinador"
                                required
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label>Auditor </label>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                className="form-control mb-4"
                                name="auditor"
                                id="auditor"
                                value={auditor}
                                onChange={(e) => setauditor(e.target.value)}
                                placeholder="Auditor"
                                required
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label>Id de Llamada </label>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                className="form-control mb-4"
                                name="id_llamada"
                                id="id_llamada"
                                value={id_llamada}
                                onChange={(e) => setid_llamada(e.target.value)}
                                placeholder="Id de Llamada"
                                required
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label>Número de Llamada</label>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                className="form-control mb-4"
                                name="num_tel"
                                id="num_tel"
                                value={num_tel}
                                onChange={(e) => setnum_tel(e.target.value)}
                                placeholder="Número de Llamada"
                                required
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label>Fecha de Llamada</label>
                            <input
                                type="date"
                                className="form-control mb-4"
                                name="f_llamada"
                                id="f_llamada"
                                value={f_llamada}
                                onChange={(e) => setf_llamada(e.target.value)}
                                placeholder="Fecha de Llamada"
                                required
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label>TMO</label>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                className="form-control mb-4"
                                name="tmo"
                                id="tmo"
                                value={tmo}
                                onChange={(e) => settmo(e.target.value)}
                                placeholder="00:15:00"
                                required
                            />
                        </div>
                        <hr />
                        <hr />
                        <div className="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label>Saludo</label>
                            <div className="input-group">
                                <div className="input-group-prepend ">
                                    <div id="divUno" className="input-group-text">
                                        3%
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <select
                                    className="form-select form-control "
                                    name="uno"
                                    id="uno"
                                    value={uno}
                                    onChange={(e) => {
                                        calcularTotal(e.target.value, 3, false, 'divUno');
                                        setuno(e.target.value);
                                    }}
                                    required
                                >
                                    <option value="1">CUMPLE</option>
                                    <option value="0">NO CUMPLE</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <hr />
                        <hr />
                        {/* <!--- VALORES CON 100% ---> */}
                        <center>
                            <h5>Ítems de alto impacto</h5>
                        </center>

                        <div className="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label>Maltrato al Cliente</label>
                            <div className="input-group">
                                <div className="input-group-prepend ">
                                    <div id="divquince" className="input-group-text">
                                        100%
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <select
                                    className="form-select form-control "
                                    name="quince"
                                    id="quince"
                                    value={quince}
                                    onChange={(e) => {
                                        calcularTotal(e.target.value, 100, true, 'divquince');
                                        setquince(e.target.value);
                                    }}
                                    required
                                >
                                    <option value="1">CUMPLE</option>
                                    <option value="0">NO CUMPLE</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label>Cuelgue de llamada</label>
                            <div className="input-group">
                                <div className="input-group-prepend ">
                                    <div id="divdieciseis" className="input-group-text">
                                        100%
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <select
                                    className="form-select form-control "
                                    name="dieciseis"
                                    id="dieciseis"
                                    value={dieciseis}
                                    onChange={(e) => {
                                        calcularTotal(e.target.value, 100, true, 'divdieciseis');
                                        setdieciseis(e.target.value);
                                    }}
                                    required
                                >
                                    <option value="1">CUMPLE</option>
                                    <option value="0">NO CUMPLE</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr />
                        <hr />
                        {/* totales ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */}
                        <div className="container">
                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="input-field col-md-4 text-center col-4">
                                    <label>Enc</label>
                                    <input
                                        className="form-control"
                                        type="text"
                                        name="enc"
                                        id="enc"
                                        value={enc + '%'}
                                        readOnly
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <div className="input-field col-md-4 text-center col-4">
                                    <label>Ec</label>
                                    <input
                                        className="form-control"
                                        type="text"
                                        name="ec"
                                        id="ec"
                                        value={ec + '%'}
                                        readOnly
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <div className="input-field col-md-4 text-center col-4">
                                    <label>Final</label>
                                    <input
                                        className="form-control"
                                        type="text"
                                        name="final"
                                        id="final"
                                        value={final + '%'}
                                        readOnly
                                    />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {/* totales ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */}

                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-block mt-4">
                            Guardar Monitoreo
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <Footer />
        </div>
    );
};
export default Create;
```

Comment: Recargar la página sería solo un parche para tu problema. Lo ideal sería detectar lo que hace que no se pueda scrolear la primera vez que entras a tu página.

Comment: Bueno, compartire mas codigo

Comment: Reduje el formulario pero aún así no funciona el scroll hasta que refresque la página

Comment: Una recomendación, intenta siempre poner tu código dentro de la pregunta porque si lo pones solo en un enlace externo, este al borrarse se perdería toda esa información. Ahora bien, en cuanto a tu código hice este [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-wu-6cq86?file=/src/App.js) para intentar recrearlo lo máximo posible y le agregué una cantidad exagerada de `<br>` para mostrarte que ahí sí es posible scrolear la página sin necesidad de recargarla. Eso me hace pensar que quizás tu problema podría estar en tu CSS o en alguna otra parte y no dentro del código de tu archivo **Create.js**.

Comment: bien. Sin embargo un plan de acción que tome fué: Al llamar la página lo hacía con <Link/> ahora lo hago con <a/>. A mi me funcionó, claro se recarga toda la página que no sería lo ideal, pero en un principio funcionó.

Comment: Gracias. Ha sido de utilidad tu post

Comment: De esa manera estarías quitándole a React la ventaja que te brinda como framework SPA (Single-page application). Pero bueno, si bien lo ideal es arrancar un problema de raíz, a veces puede ser útil esconderlo bajo la alfombra si no se dispone del tiempo necesario para solucionarlo. Quizás más adelante encuentres lo que provoca tu problema.

Answer (score 0):

para solucionar el scroll, tuve que configurar las cors en el index del server:

```
// Enables CORS
app.use(cors(
  {
    origin: ['http://localhost:3000'],
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'],
    credentials: true,
    origin: true
  }
));
```

Ahora si funciona con `<Link to=""/>` como lo esperaba.
Muchas gracias, saludos...